# How can I create a repeatable signature of a data structure?

Tags: perl, data-structures, signature

I have a situation where I want to create a signature of a data structure:

```
my $signature = ds_to_sig(
  { foo   => 'bar',
    baz   => 'bundy',
    boing => undef,
    number => 1_234_567,
  }
);
```

The aim should be that if the data structure changes then so should the signature.

Is there an established way to do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The best way to do this is to use a deep-structure serialization system like [Storable](http://search.cpan.org/~ams/Storable-2.18/Storable.pm). Two structures with the same data will produce the same blob of Storable output, so they can be compared.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Storable ('freeze');

$Storable::canonical = 1;

my $one = { foo => 42, bar => [ 1, 2, 3 ] };
my $two = { foo => 42, bar => [ 1, 2, 3 ] };

my $one_s = freeze $one;
my $two_s = freeze $two;

print "match\n" if $one_s eq $two_s;
```

...And to prove the inverse:

```
$one = [ 4, 5, 6 ];
$one_s = freeze $one;

print "no match" if $one_s ne $two_s;
```

Comment: You need to set $Storable::canonical to a true value. It might not matter in little examples, but it matters in much larger ones.

Answer (score 16):

I think what you're looking for is a hash function. I would recommend an approach like this:

```
use Storable;
$Storable::canonical = 1;
sub ds_to_sig {
    my $structure = shift;
    return hash(freeze $structure);
}
```

The function hash can be any hash function, for example the function md5 from [Digest::MD5](http://search.cpan.org/~gaas/Digest-MD5/MD5.pm)

Comment: Hehe. two virtually identical answers in less than 2 minutes.

Comment: Make that 3 in 3 minutes! I guess that can only mean we've got it right ;-)

Comment: The key there is $Storable::canonical. Without that, Storable doesn't guarantee the order of the elements.

Comment: You should probably be using 'nfreeze' for cross platform consistency

Answer (score 7):

Use [Storable](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Storable)::nstore to turn it into a binary representation, and then calculate a checksum (for example with the Digest module).

Both modules are core modules.

Comment: I had just edited my code to do exactly that. You and I are on the same track again!

Answer (score 5):

```
Digest::MD5->new->add(
  Data::Dumper->new([$structure])
   ->Purity(0)
   ->Terse(1)
   ->Indent(0)
   ->Useqq(1)
   ->Sortkeys(1)
   ->Dump()
)->b64digest();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you're looking for is ["hashing"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).

Basically, you put your data structure through a function that generates a fairly unique value from it. This value would be your signiture.

Answer (score -5):

Can't you use an object instead of a struct?  That way you could see if an object is an instance of a type without having to compare hashes, etc.

Comment: data structures and objects are largely interchangeable in Perl 5 - objects are really just blessed data references. Either way - I want to get a signature of the contents of the data

Comment: The real problem with this approach is that he's after the data.  Since the data is used to maintain state on objects, you'd have to instantiate a new object every time the state changed, thus negating this approach.